# VBA For Next Loop is stopping after second row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a loop of checks to perform on a variable number of rows of data. This code works just fine on another report, but when copied and tweaked to check this report it is stopping the loop after 2 rows and then moving onto the next conditional formatting/sort in the code. I've googled and played around with this all day.. it seems that the last row is defined correctly and the For/Next is set up as it should be, so I cannot figure out why it's stopping. Do you guys have any ideas? I can add more code and context if you need it.

```
Dim sht As Worksheet, rw As Long
Dim LR As Long, rngRed As Range, rngRow As Range

Set sht = Sheets("Page1_1")

sht.Rows("1:4").Delete Shift:=xlUp 'delete cognos headers

LR = sht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For rw = 2 To LR
    Set rngRed = Nothing   'reset range for problem cells

    With sht.Rows(rw)
        Set rngRow = .Cells(1).Resize(1, MAX_COLS) 'the row of data
        'clear any previous fill
        rngRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

        'perform your checks
        If Len(.Cells(1, "A").Value) = 0 Then BuildRange rngRed, .Cells(1, "A")
        If Len(.Cells(1, "A").Value) = 0 Then BuildRange rngRed, .Cells(1, "B")
        If (.Cells(1, "B").Value) <= Date Then BuildRange rngRed, .Cells(1, "A")
        If (.Cells(1, "B").Value) <= Date Then BuildRange rngRed, .Cells(1, "B")
        If (.Cells(1, "G").Value) = "999999" Then BuildRange rngRed, .Cells(1, "G")
        If Len(.Cells(1, "G").Value) = 0 Then BuildRange rngRed, .Cells(1, "G")
        If Len(.Cells(1, "I").Value) = 0 Then BuildRange rngRed, .Cells(1, "I")
        If Len(.Cells(1, "J").Value) = 0 Then BuildRange rngRed, .Cells(1, "J")
        'done checking

        If Not rngRed Is Nothing Then
            'found some problems, so color the row and then the problem cells
            rngRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            rngRed.Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If

    End With
Next rw
```

It generates no debug or error messages, saves the file correctly, but only performs the checks on rows 1 and 2.

Comment: First of all you can't place `If ... Then ...` in one line of code. Second of all you are missing about 8 instances of `End If`, so this code could never have worked in any sheet...

Comment: There's nothing in column A, i.e. `LR=1`.

Comment: @DannyPapadopulos - you can do it on one line.

Comment: @Danny Papadopulos - Yes you can -- see the one line syntax provided in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/if-then-else-statement)

Comment: Oh I didn't know, it looks so nasty to code like that I wouldn't have ever thought somebody would use that. Anyway, where are all those `End If`s?

Comment: @DannyPapadopulos For single line IF THEN no END IF is required.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. At least I learned that. However I have no idea who would want to use this, makes the code 1000 chars wide lol

Comment: Add LR and RW to you watch list and see what their values are as you step through the code.  Set a break point at your NEXT RW line to step through the first two iterations faster then step through 1 line at a time to see what is tripping.

Comment: use `Option Explicit` and declare all your variables !

Comment: @DannyPapadopulos I tend to use it for simple short single line "then" commands  'IF progress = 100 then Done = True'.  Saves cluttering with excess ENDIF.

Comment: problem solved! A was not always populated so stopped the count, using D works. thanks guys!

Comment: looks like you're deleting rows 1-4 at the very beginning and then looping over (new) row 2 - the last row that has data in it in column A (your LR var). I would add some debugging to figure out what it thinks LR is:

```
LR = sht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

MsgBox LR
```

Comment: @DannyPapadopulos I agree block syntax should be used most of the time, but inline/statement syntax is rather useful for guard clauses, e.g. `If Not condition Then Exit Sub` at the top of a procedure.

Comment: after `LR = sht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` in the next line type `Debug.Print LR`. Step thru the code and see what value is printed to the immeadiate window